# How to Change Column Group Header Color in SSRS on every new value

Tags: asp.net, ssas, ssrs-2008-r2

i have a column group in matrix report i want to change the background color of column on every value Change[image]

Please Suggest very Helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use expression like this it show alternative color in columns

```
=IIF((ColNumber(nothing) MOD 2)=1,"Gainsboro","Transparent")
```

Please also see the below link as well it will help you

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2612/data-driven-colored-text-for-reporting-services-reports/

Comment: colNumber is not any function exist in SSRS

Comment: Yes it is not there you have to create the custom function with the help of below link http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/count-columns-ssrs-59690.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As of now i put the condition like if Month(Date) = "JAN","RED","Blue") like this i put 12 condition.